# Display a ASP.NET form in .Net Core Blazor server Application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a new Blazor server application. I want to display a page/form from another Asp.NET application.
What will be the best secure way to display a online page or ASP.NET application page in the blazor Application?

Answer (score 2):

I use the documentation from microsoft allot.
Here is a link with help to make a Blazor form.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Hi BOT, For clarity, I have 2 separate applications. one is written in ASP.NET and another is in NET.CORE Blazor server. I need to access ASP.NET pages from the blazor application.